# CSS - Mobile devices put a grey gradient at the top of text inputs

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

I have noticed that mobile devices often contain a small grey gradient at the top of `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>`. For example the following code produces this problem on mobile:

```html
<input type="text">
```

produces:

[image: Text Box]

I was wondering what CSS I could use to remove that gradient?

Thank You - All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-webkit-appearance: none;` removed the gradient fine.